# Unhandled Format

Tags: vb.net, exception

I am a student working on a `Visual Basic` and I copied the following code exactly how the book said to:

```
 intNumberofBikes = Convert.ToInt32(strNumberofBikes)
```

I am getting an error of the following:
[VbScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ewsou.png)

Any help would be appreciated, I cannot find out what is wrong with the code.

Comment: `strNumberOfBikes` is presumably a variable of type `String`, which can contain non-numeric values. Trying to convert these values to a number usually causes this error.

Comment: Thank you for your response Zev. What variable type would I use besides string to stop throwing this error? This is exactly what the book wants me to input. Hmmm.

Comment: Please read [ask] and take the [tour].  Links to pictures of code or error messages are not well received: it makes it hard for future visitors to search for the help with the same error.  And we do not need tags in the title.

Comment: I apologize @Plutonix I will do that. Honestly, it would help because I have no idea how to use this site. Thank you

Comment: `strNumberofBikes` is empty `""` so you have to enter a number in the textbox

Comment: You can check the values of your variables in the `Autos` window when the error is thrown. It's even shown in the bottom of your screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

The error is because you have a character in the text field that is not numeric... Try this below...

```
 Dim intBikes As Integer = 0 
 Integer.TryParse(strNumberofBikes, intBikes)
```

The error will go away and `intBikes` will be the count if it successfully parses the text field.

The whole thing wrapped up...

```
 Dim intBikes As Integer
 Dim decTotalCost As Decimal 
 If Integer.TryParse(txtNumberOfBikes.Text, intBikes) Then
    decTotalCost = intBikes * _cdecPricePerBike
    lblTotalCost.Text = decTotalCost.ToString("C")
 End If
```

Comment: Thank you for the response Zaggler. I will try the code you linked. Im wondering if the book did this purposely to see if i could correct the error? Thank you

Comment: Maybe so, but always sanitize the input's; user's cant be trusted we have to help them :)

Comment: This is true lol VB is the first coding I've done besides HTML and CSS which hardly count. So I'm very new to all the procedures and terminology. Got a long way to go!

Comment: Reason for down vote would be good, so I can improve the answer?

Comment: No idea why the downvote. The answer should solve the problem and it utilizes good practice. +1

Comment: @Siodinn If this fixes your problem, the thing to do is to click the checkmark.  This will move it off the Unanswered list and help future visitors find good answers. The very brief [Tour] explains how SO works.

Comment: Thanks guys, I appreciate it. It may not be perfect, but the problem can be resolved in more than a few ways. Maybe the dv was because it wasn't to their likings?